# export sqlite to cvs Xcode objective-C

Tags: ios, email, sqlite, export-to-csv, core-data-migration

Good morning:
Anybody know how to export a database in sqlite3 to csv from a app and send by email.
I have a table call Patient and I want push a button in the app and all de table with the dates of all patient will send by email. I need that programatically.
Thank you for all.